# Why does comma appear in my Xquery and how to get rid of it?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, xquery-3.0

I have an xml file which looks like this.

```
   <Movies>
     <Movie>

          <Title>1 2 3</Title>

          <Year>1985</Year>
     </Movie>
  </Movies>
```

I am trying to run this xquery.

```
   let $alltitles := Movies//Movie/Title
   let $allyear := Movies//Movie/Year
   let $d :=concat($alltitles/text(),',',$allyear/text())
return $d.
```

But when that returns it says 1, 2 , 3.

Why is comma automatically added? and how do I get  the title without having commas in them?

Comment: Do you mean `let $alltitles := Movies//Title`?

Comment: @mike yes sorry. thats how i have my query

Comment: @user2775042 have you tested that *exact* query with the *exact* XML input? Because in [my testing](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/6615e7981e6baca7b470bca4acbeb441), the output was : `1 2 3,1985`

Comment: I get the same result as @har07 when testing in BaseX 8.4.2.

Comment: @har07 no. my xml is a very long file. but the query is exactly the same. I got around it by adding quotation marks before the title. When I add the quotation, the comma disappears.

Comment: @user2775042 That's understandable that the actual XML is long and the one posted here is a simplified version of it. But you should post a simplified XML that still showing the problem (the one you posted didn't yield the unwanted commas)

Comment: I do not get the commas when trying out here: http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery. Instead I get the same output as har07.

Comment: In 8.2.3, I got `1 2 3,1985` (After removing the trailing period from your query).